# How can we fix the orientation for one view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Can we fix the orientation for one imageview in framelayout, and orientation of other children of frame layout be controlled by  the sensor?

I want to fix the orientation of image in background and on top of that need to show some reults in textviews. If I fix the activity in landscape then I can't draw the text portrait wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use separate xml for portrait and landscape mode.

1.you have to create separate folders **layout-land**, **layout-port**

2.save the xml in it.

3.Be sure with both have the same name.

You can refer [here](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/03/how-to-handle-screen-orientation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Orientation can only be applied on activities,we cannot set the orientation of views.